# jQuery ajax - set values in next container

Tags: jquery, ajax

i try to load with ajax inside of next subcontainer if i click on load Class befor. But it do not work. Why? 
If click on the load-class next subcontainer change the color but i do not get new contant.

My HTML-Code.

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div class="load" data-id="1"></div>
 <div class="subcontainer"></div>
 <div class="load" data-id="2"></div>
 <div class="subcontainer"></div>
 <div class="load" data-id="3"></div>
 <div class="subcontainer"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

My script

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#wrapper > .load", function () {
var abc = $(this).next(".subcontainer").css({"background-color", "red"});           
// It works.
var name_id = $(this).data("id").val();

 $.ajax({
   url: "folder/get-data.php",
   method: "POST",
   data: {id: name_id},
   dataType: "html",
   cache: false,

 success: function (result) {
  $("#wrapper > .subcontainer").html(result); // Do not work.
   },
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Typo, `subcontainer` is not the same as `subkontainer`

Comment: Yes, but it is just an example. Have you an idea why it do not work???

Comment: where is name_id??

Comment: sorry, i have edit it now

Comment: Isn't  "var name_id = $(this).data("id").val();"   should be    "var name_id = $(this).data("data-id").val();"

Comment: Have anybody an idea if i set between <div class="load" data-id="1"><p></p></div> <div class="subcontainer"></div> a p-Tag, how can i select .subcontainer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing ajax response content in all subcontainers instead of the next subcontainer

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#wrapper > .load", function() {
    var that = this;
    var abc = $(this).next(".subcontainer").css({
        "background-color",
        "red"
    }); // It works.
    var name_id = $(this).data("id").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "folder/get-data.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: name_id
        },
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,

        success: function(result) {
            $(that).next(".subcontainer").html(result);
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

And replace this line also `$(this).data("id").val()`
with `$(this).data("id")`

You can use `.nextAll()` method also to get the required elements

You can use any of the following codes,

1) `$(that).nextAll(".subcontainer")[0].innerHTML = result`

2) `$($(that).nextAll(".subcontainer")[0]).html(result)`

Comment: Have you an idea if i set between  <div class="load" data-id="1"><p></p></div>
 <div class="subcontainer"></div> a p-Tag, how can i select .subcontainer??

Comment: you want to select `p` or `.subcontainer` ?

Comment: i want to select .subcontainer after p-Tag

Comment: You have given this `<div class="load" data-id="1"><p></p></div> <div class="subcontainer"></div>` but your question is related to this i think `<div class="load" data-id="1"><p></p><div class="subcontainer"></div></div>` right?

Comment: sorry i mean this  <div class="load" data-id="1"></div><p></p><div class="subcontainer"></div> if i set p-tag i can not select .subcontainer. Yes you are right.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is if i use .nextAll i will select every .subcontainer on the page and i get the content in every .subcontainer

Comment: @Juergen please check the updated answer, take very first element from the array so that it will fetch nearest element